# How do I live stream with 2 Cameras and 1 MacBook Air?

Tags: usb, camera, streaming

For live streaming purposes, is it possible to input two cameras (DLSR with HDMI out) into a MacBook Air which only has 2 USB-C ports? Is there a USB C device which can do this? Thanks

Comment: There is more to it than just hardware. What kind of software are you using for streaming? Also, what research have you already done on this and what did you find which didn't work?

Comment: hi @JTheBiker  Do the cameras have WiFi ?

Comment: I have found some software for the Mac named OBS which looks highly recommended and allows you to switch between cameras and a program named Camera Live which allows the DSLR to be used as a web cam on the mac. I have looked for hardware by searching 'USB C HDMI Capture' and similar but I haven't seen a product that allows two HDMI inputs to USB C.

Comment: @ankii Hi, The camera is a canon 80D, it does have wifi but I think this is just to connect to a canon smart phone app.